# How can noodles (the lines that connect nodes) be changed from straight to curved lines?

Tags: customization, node-editor

Unitl now I haven't found the option to enable the curved representation of connectors between nodes. The [documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Node_Controls) doesn't mention such an  option. Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I thought curved was the default? (maybe you mean from curved to straight?)

Comment: @gandalf3 Just installed 2.68a and wondered why all tutorials looked different.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The option can be found in *User Preferences > Themes* under *Node Editor*:
Higher values will increase the curviness of noodles. Setting it to 0 will make them straight line.

For 2.7#
[image]

For 2.8#
[image]

Comment: Lovely that you connect nodes with noodles :D