# How to set up mathematical expressions in the title of Gometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I sometimes see different nodes in screenshots that contain a mathematical formula/expression instead of the expected title.

[image]

[image]

How do you do that?

Comment: You need to add more details than just an image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are simply manually renamed nodes.

You can change the title of each node individually by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, or by entering a value in the *Label* field via the *N-Panel*, or by pressing <kbd>RMB</kbd> and selecting *Rename*.

Renaming the node individually does not change the original function, only the title.

> PS: If you change the title, and shrink the node as shown in the screenshot, make sure that the node tree is still understandable for others if you want to share it. Otherwise, the situation will arise that others will not know what the node is actually about.
>
> See: [How can I better structure my node tree and make it easier for others to understand?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266334/how-can-i-better-structure-my-node-tree-and-make-it-easier-for-others-to-underst)

Comment: Your PS is really important I think. I sometimes see it when people give answers here that they also use things like Ctrl+H to hide unused sockets etc. No problem if you do that for yourself, but especially for newbies it can be quite confusing even if a title of a node might be original, that it seems to have different inputs and outputs than the one they've got in their Blender.

Comment: Ok, I see it is just a commented nodes. Thanks, for quick answer

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You are absolutely right! I must confess, I also often hide the sockets that are not needed, or those that simply use the default values, because in many cases it is necessary to save the space. However, I also try to do it always according to the previous knowledge of the questioner ...but I also do not always succeed. Please forgive me ;-)

Comment: @MateuszHanula You are welcome!

Comment: @quellenform No problem ;) I didn't have you in mind when I wrote this... I use to hide sockets and collaps nodes a lot, too. But I try not to do it here either - because it's not always easy to determine the knowledge of a questioner and even less the knowledge of people coming afterwards having the same problem. Especially when questions are marked as duplicate it can be problematic when you're a noob and the link is an answer for experts ;)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the header color of node indicates the node type. The light blue one is a simple "Math" node, and the purple one is a "Vector Math" node

[image: Math nodes]

You can change the labels from any node in Nodes properties panel

[image: Change node label]