# How to place nodes at default position?

Tags: shader-nodes

When I clicked a new button in shading mode, a node was created in a corner

[image]

I want the node to be created in the middle when it is created.

Do you know how to place nodes at default position?

Comment: Press the Home key to centre the view.

Comment: This happened probably because in some node tree you have your output moved away from the original spot. Then you switch to a new node tree, and the view's location doesn't change, but since view 'camera' is far away from origin, you have a problem finding the nodes. This is why it is [advised](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/266334/60486) to never move your output.

Comment: Or you can use the trick of mine to restore the position of output: Go to the previous node tree, select the output node, then Shift + F4, paste this code `C.area.type='NODE_EDITOR';o=Vector({'C':(300,400),'S':(300,300),'G':(200,0)}[C.area.ui_type[0]])-C.active_node.location;nodes=(n for n in C.active_node.id_data.nodes if not n.parent);exec('for n in nodes: n.location+=o')` enter. Now if you move your view (middle mouse button) to see the output, and switch to a new node tree, the nodes will spawn where you expect them.

Answer (score 3):

Clik <kbd>Home</kbd> key while hovering mouse over Node Editor to frame all nodes or <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to frame selected.